# Possible to embed multiple MoviePlayer instances on a iPad-screen?

Tags: iphone, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

is there a way to play multiple movieplayer-view at the same time?
I´ve tested that with 3 different buttons which loads a video in there own view. But only one instance is playing at the same time. The other videos stops playing.
Is that true or did i something wrong? 
Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`MPMoviePlayerController`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html) documentation:

> **Note**: Although you may create multiple `MPMoviePlayerController` objects and present their views in your interface, only one movie player at a time may play its movie.